# Connexion object singleton in react native

Tags: react-native, service, websocket, kuzzle

I'm trying to create a singleton service class in which I instanciate a connection object, which connect to the backend, in order to reuse the connection object in every component, so I've done that:

```
const {
Kuzzle,
WebSocket
 } = require('kuzzle-sdk');

class KuzzleService {

static instance = null;
static async createInstance() {
    var object = new KuzzleService();
    object.kuzzle = new Kuzzle(
        new WebSocket('localhost'),{defaultIndex: 'index'}
    );
    await object.kuzzle.connect();
    const credentials = { username: 'user', password: 'pass' };
    const jwt = await object.kuzzle.auth.login('local', credentials);
    return object;
}

static async getInstance () {
    if (!KuzzleService.instance) {
        KuzzleService.instance = await KuzzleService.createInstance();
    }
    return KuzzleService.instance;
}

}
const kuzzleService = KuzzleService.getInstance();
export default kuzzleService;
```

But when I import the service in a component as follow:

```
import kuzzleService from "../services/kuzzle-service.js";
```

And I print that:

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(kuzzleService.kuzzle));
 }
```

It gives me "undefined". Should I import the service another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because when you export `kuzzleService`, the promise given by `.getInstance()` isn't resolved yet.

You should export the `.getInstance` function and await it in `componentDidMount`, like that:

```
export default KuzzleService; // export the singleton directly
```

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const kuzzle = await KuzzleService.getInstance();
    console.log(kuzzle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kuzzle team ;)